# How to load different jni libs according to CPU abilities in android?

Tags: android

I have several jni dynamic libs (*.so), which related to cpu abilities, for example, some libs support armv7+neon cpu, some libs support armv7+vfpv3 cpu, some libs support non-armv7 cpus.

How to load them dynamically according to the CPU abilities?

I tried the following code, but not work.

In this solution, I put 3 libs version in the install package with different names below: 
(Original name is libavcodec.so)

1. libavcodec_neon.so and libavutil_neon.so
2. libavcodec_vfpv3.so and libavutil_vfpv3.so
3. libavcodec_basic.so and libavutil_basic.so

But libavcodec.so depends on libavutil.so, so the loadLibrary function will fail because its name has been changed.

Maybe I can rename the libs to the original name before load them, how to do it?

```
   String cpu_ability = getCpuAbility();    

    if (cpu_ability.equals("cpuinfo_armv7_neon")) {
        System.loadLibrary("avutil_neon");
        System.loadLibrary("avcodec_neon");
    }
    else if (cpu_ability.equals("cpuinfo_armv7_vfpv3")) {
        System.loadLibrary("avutil_vfpv3");
        System.loadLibrary("avcodec_vfpv3");
    }
    else {
        System.loadLibrary("avutil_basic");
        System.loadLibrary("avcodec_basic");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to solve this question.

Because the directory `/data/data/<appname>/lib` can't be modified, I copied the library to the `/data/data/<appname>/files` directory, and renamed it.

For example, in armv7+neon situation, I copied libavcodec_neon.so to the `files` directory, and rename it to libavcodec.so. So does other libs. Then load them from the `files` directory.